# UITapGestureRecogniser not working after switching back to the viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added Tap gesture on on containerview subview. Tapgesture action is not triggering when i switch back to the the view controller from menu. Intial root view is loading from storyboard. when coming from home its switching root view as following code.

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate;
 appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 UIViewController *vc ;
 vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HomeView"];
[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance]popAllAndSwitchToViewController:vc withCompletion:nil];
```

I tried printing by the all gesture recognisers to confirm gesture is added or not.

```
NSArray *gestureRecognizers = self.view.gestureRecognizers;
```

O/P

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x282dcab80>(
<UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x2813eba00; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x10d21c1c0>; target= <(action=didTapGesture:, target=<TV2ZPlayerOverlayVC 0x106016600>)>>
)
```

TapGesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapGesture:)];
tap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Comment: How are you adding tap gesture? show some code related to it

Comment: check my edit ..

Comment: It looks good...please verify that after switching back to the view controller...user interaction is enabled or not for the view.

Comment: Add below two line and check [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1]; self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: i tried that but not solved @RajeshDharani